# Azure SQL DB: Programmatic Backup and Restore

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am working on an automation infrastructure for an Azure based product. I need the ability to programmatically (no manual UI intervention work allowed) backup and restore an Azure SQL DB. I am looking for the appropriate RESTFul api's but don't see any that fit the bill. Perhaps I missed it ??

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Not exact thing i came across till now. but you can refer something like this(all are in preview mostly). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-08-01-preview/managed-databases/complete-restore

Answer (score 1):

To **Export** (Backup) the Azure SQL Database, you can use the below HTTP POST request.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}/export?api-version=2021-02-01-preview
```

To know about the URI parameters required in above request, go through this [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-02-01-preview/databases/export#uri-parameters).

For **Restore**, you can use `Azure PowerShell` or the `REST API`. There are some PowerShell commands you need to learn to accomplish this task. Learn about these commands here [Restore-AzSqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/restore-azsqldatabase?view=azps-7.4.0).

Useful link: [Programmatic recovery using automated backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups#programmatic-recovery-using-automated-backups)

Comment: Hey @Walter!, has it solved your problem; else can you share more details so I can troubleshoot the issue?